# Gyroscope gives different values on different devices

Tags: android

I have strange gyroscope behavior:

I have `values[0]` from gyroscope sensor: Angular speed around the x-axis.
On Samsung Galaxy Nexus this value is from -10 to 10.
In Samsung Galaxy Tab(old) - from -100 to 100.

So, why? I can't understand. I write application which use gyroscope. On Galaxy Nexus everything is ok, but on Galaxy Tab because of greater values i have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any [Sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) returned by Android's [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) will provide the range of values provided by that sensor.  Your calculations should be based on that, not a hard-coded value.

Answer (score 0):

if the devices give different values the only reason that comes to my mind is that they are working on different range/scales...
meaning you probably have to divide your values by the max range in order to normalize the values.

Answer (score 0):

Old 7" Samsung Galaxy Tab also provides gyroscope's data in radians/seconds. This is not about scale or whatever, the value is either simply wrong or you don't get it correctly. Range values inform you on min and max obtainable values, that's all.